# Do I need to chroot BIND 9 if I'm using AppArmor?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, selinux, chroot, apparmor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bind9 in a chroot jail - necessary or not?](https://serverfault.com/questions/307641/bind9-in-a-chroot-jail-necessary-or-not)

I'm redoing my external dns servers and thinking about skipping chroot this time.
And using apparmor or selinux as an alternativen. Any thoughts?

I'm using team cymrus bind template as ..template :)
But when more ppl are administrating the servers, default packages are prefered imho.

Answer (score 3):

I'm absolutely not a security expert, so anything I say is IMHO.

Running BIND as root without apparmor/chroot/selinux is not a sin. (BIND9 **never** had [known vulnerabilities](http://www.isc.org/software/bind/security/matrix) allowing code execution.)

Running it unprivileged is better.

Running under apparmor is even better.

Running both - under apparmor and unprivileged is even better.

(Besides, apparmor vs chroot - apparmor is probably preferred.)