# Process separation on an OpenBSD server

Tags: vps, service, best-practices, openbsd

I fear this may be a somewhat open-ended question that gets closed: Apologies in advance, but I'll give it a shot!

I'm considering operating an OpenBSD VM with a number of services running on the same instance (SSH, IMAP, SMTP, some HTTP server and VPN). Should I sandbox these daemons, some how (e.g., chroot jails), to ensure they don't interfere with each other, or is the OpenBSD/POSIX model already sufficient? Is there anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/307641/bind9-in-a-chroot-jail-necessary-or-not

Comment: So it sounds like minimising attack surface using chroots for services (which are run as their own user, rather than root) is generally a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Most of OpenBSD’s internal daemons are already privilege separated and chrooted.

Comment: Although this answer is short, it is not low quality.